# How create Android different notification every time?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Notification work normally one problem is All notification go to last notification link. How can I fix it? Every notification go to it's own link. Every message notification go to he's/she's inbox. How can I do that?

```
Intent intent_activity_start = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                intent_activity_start.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent_activity_start.putExtra("links", c.getString("link"));

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent_activity_start,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setLargeIcon(getCircleBitmap(photoStream(c.getString("profile_photo"))));
                builder.setContentTitle("Title");
                builder.setContentText(c.getString("notify"));
                builder.setSound(notificationSound);
                builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(c.getString("notify")));
                if(!c.getString("photo").equals("null")){
                    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(photoStream(c.getString("photo"))));
                }



                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(counter.incrementAndGet(), builder.build());
```

Comment: Currently, whatsapp its just showing one notification that shows "x messages of y chats" so...

Comment: @Nanoc yes You are right. But how can I create different notification every time?

Comment: Im not really sure... maybe its limited to one per package name?

Comment: Your app package name, defined in your manifest file.

Comment: Instead of passing `0` as the request code in `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, pass a unique `int` each time, like you are in the `notify()` call. In fact, you could use the same value for both.

Comment: @MikeM. Will that make a new notification each time??

Comment: @Nanoc It'll behave the same way it does now, except the `Intent` extras will be different for each unique request code, instead of all of them being the last one issued.